Why $\text{rank}(L)=\dim(Z_{h})$?
Gaussian Hidden Variable Graphical Model
Suppose we have Gaussian distributed observed variables $Z_o$ and hidden variables $Z_h$. The joint precision matrix $K_{(o,h)}$ associated with these variables is given by:
$$
K_{(o,h)} = \begin{bmatrix} K_o & K_{o,h} \\ K_{h,o} & K_h \end{bmatrix}.
$$
According to Schur complement, the marginalized precision matrix $\tilde{K}_o$ of $Z_o$ can be written as:
$$
\tilde{K}_o = K_o - K_{o,h} K_h^{-1} K_{h,o} = K_o - L,
$$
with product matrix $L = K_{o,h} K_h^{-1} K_{h,o}$. Those two components have specific properties : $K_o$ is the supposedly sparse conditional precision matrix of $Z_o$, conditioned on $Z_h$; the product matrix $L$ summarizes the effect of marginalization over the hidden variables. The rank of that matrix (equal to the number of hidden variables $Z_h$) is low, since the number of hidden variables is supposed to be small.
Given i.i.d. samples of $Z_o$, our objective is to estimate $K_o$ and $L$; we are especially interested in ${\color{red}{\text{the rank of }L}}$, since ${\color{red}{\text{ it equals the number of hidden variables } Z_h}}$.Those matrices may be recovered by solving the convex relaxation:
$$
(\hat{K}_o, \hat{L}) = \underset{K_o, L}{\text{argmin}} \, \text{trace}((K_o - L)\Sigma_o) - \log \det(K_o - L) + \lambda(\gamma \|K_o\|_1 + \text{trace}(L)),
$$
where $\hat{K}_o$ and $\hat{L}$ are the estimates of $K_o$ and $L$ respectively, and $\Sigma_o$ is the empirical marginal covariance of $Z_o$.

According to basic matrix theory , the rank of $L$ should be less than or equal to $\dim(Z_h)$,the number of hidden variables. I find it difficult to understand why many references directly equate the rank of $L$ with $\dim(Z_h)$. What is the theoretical justification and practical significance of this approach?

The rank of this matrix $L$ bounded by $\mathrm{dim}(Z_o)$. Thus to me it seems that one has to assume at least that $\mathrm{dim}(Z_o) \ge \mathrm{dim}(Z_h)$.
If that was the case and the covariance matrix $K_{(o,h)}$ was an absolutely continuous random variable w.r.t. to the Lebesgue measure one might be able to show that $L$ is full rank with probability $1$.
But as is it seems like choosing the hidden variables of higher dimension already disproofs the claim in question.
